# How does cpu gets interrupted by APIC and how to handle shared interrupts?

Tags: interrupts

From the very little knowledge i have, every `PCI` device has 4 interrupt pins. Pins from the many different `PCI` devices on the motherboard (Built-in or external devices) are routed to an `IO-APIC` (Advanced programmable interrupt controller) through a programmable interrupt router. So that was the topology.
As far as i know when an interrupt occur, the `IO-APIC` will be signaled and it will raise an INT to the CPU then magic happens and CPU starts executing an ISR (Interrupt Service Routine).
What was that magic ? 
What is the communication that should happen between the CPU and the `IO-APIC` to handle the INT ?
 I mean how does the CPU received the interrupt vector (is it a special `PCI` bus cycle ?) & what will happen if the the `IRQ` was shared by many devices (Take `x86 Linux` as a platform reference)  ?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/218179/can-someone-explain-to-me-how-the-cpu-finds-the-source-of-an-interrupt-in-os-the

Comment: @Mokubai that link didn't answer my question.

Comment: Hence I said it was related and not a duplicate. It may be tangential and provide information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt vector is already stored in the interrupt vector table, so the CPU doesn't need to get it from a peripheral. If the interrupt is associated with an IO-APIC or similar device that can raise interrupts for different reasons, the interrupt handler will query that device to find out why it raised the interrupt. There's no special bus cycle for this, it's the same way a CPU would get any information from one of its peripherals.